# How do I figure out what mode this Pater Noster is in?

Tags: theory

I have been singing this Pater Noster: [image: Pater Noster]

Before Pater Noster starts we have the Oremus. Let's assume that C is Do.
Then the recitation notes, we have two, would be A and B. This seems strange to me. The finalis would be A.

When Pater Noster starts the recitation note would be B and G the finalis.
Then at "sed libera..." we have the same finalis but go back to A as the recitation note.

In another sheet music for this melody we have something, what I think, is a bit strange going on.
[image]

This version seems to assume C as Do.
If so, then they have changed the melody. If they assume Bb as Do they would have two flats instead of just one. This is strange. It thought it was in some kind of Lydian mode before I saw the Gregorian sheet music.
The melody does sound more major than minor.

How do I figure out what mode this Pater Noster is in?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer. But I am confused by your confusion about the sheet music. What do you mean by "This version seems to assume C as Do. If so, then they have changed the melody"? They are clearly taking Bb for the original keynote, and the melody is unchanged. They have made a decision to harmonise the melody using E naturals instead of Eb's. As a practical choice catering for modern ears this seems reasonable since the melody sits comfortably in F major, and feels more awkward to harmonise with Eb's (although you could do a version which avoids E's altogether).

Comment: @PiedPiper this question is much less basic than "What key is this song in?".

Comment: @JamesMartin in the terminology of Solesmes, for example in the US edition of the _Liber usualis,_ the C clef is the _Doh_ clef and pitch is explicitly relative.  Thus, putting the chant into modern notation where the "doh clef" is C -- in other words, without transposition -- may be called "using C for doh."  Since the modern arrangement shown here has transposed it down a whole step ("use B flat for doh"), one would indeed normally expect two flats in the signature, but as you note it's quite natural to use the one-flat signature because of considerations of harmony and tonality.

Comment: I thought it was Lydian since it had Mi as the recitation note.

Comment: In Guidonian solmization, A is only mi in the soft hexachord.  This piece does not use the soft hexachord.  The modern harmonization is transposed down a whole step, but, as @JamesMartin notes, harmonized in the key of F major rather than in F mixolydian.  It is not particularly unusual for a harmonization to use a different key from the melodic mode, especially since neither major and minor keys (nor Ionian and Aeolian modes) existed in the medieval music theory.

Comment: It closely resembles Psalm Tone 1 but notated up a step. Normally that tone would begin F-G-A, mediant G-Bb-A-G-A, final A-G-F-G-A-A. Psalm tone 1 matches with mode 1 but they are not the same thing. Not every chant is in a mode. Mode is mostly helpful for matching chants with antiphons, which you wouldn't need to do here.

Comment: @musarithmia that is a good point, but nonetheless psalm tone 1 being in mode 1 implies a final of D, which isn't the case here.

Comment: In the square notation, the first pitch is A but all pitch is relative. This would be solmized in the hard hexachord (on G) where G-A-B is ut-re-mi (do was invented later). In the harmonized example, the same melody is notated in the soft hexachord (on F), where F-G-A is ut-re-mi. As a description of how the melody sounds, both notations achieve the same effect and are equivalent (ignoring the harmonization).

Answer (score 4):

Consensus online seems to be that it is very early chant, which explains its lack of compliance with the usual description of the medieval ecclesiastical modes.  The closest fit is hypomixolydian, since the final is G and the melody ranges below the final.  This would normally mean a reciting tone of C, but here we have a reciting tone of A.  Well, this won't be the last time that a theoretical framework fails to describe a piece of music.

The fact that a modern harmonization has transposed it down a whole step but harmonized it in F instead of B flat doesn't have any bearing on the modal analysis of the melody in medieval theory.  Had the original melody included some Fs the arranger might have made a different choice, but as noted by James Martin in the comments, harmonizing this chant tonally is natural for modern ears (and a tendency to raise the leading tone in the mixolydian and hypomixolydian modes was one of the forces leading toward the development of tonality).

Speaking of that, there is no such thing as *do* in medieval music theory.  I am not an expert in solmization, but the entire tune fits in the hard hexachord except for that one E, so that would mean that the initial A of the *oremus* is *re* with the G of *pater* being *ut,*  Only the E requires mutation to the natural hexachord, where it is mi.  The remainder of the chant requires mutation back to the hard hexachord because of the B.

By the 19th century, church musicians were using modern solfège syllables, where C is *do* and B is *si,* so in this sense "fixed do," but the pitch was not absolute, so in that sense "movable do."

Comment: In Gregorian chant notation we have a Fa clef and a Do clef. We really do!   And yes, the A would be Re as you said.

Comment: It is also interesting to note that we have some chants with only three notes. The theory of church modes do not seem to be made with those in mind. So standard theory can be problematic in certain cases?

Comment: @harryjansson the Do and Fa clefs are originally C and F clefs, which is why they have the shape of those letters.  The idea of calling them Do and Fa clefs could not have arisen before the late Renaissance.  (And in medieval theory, C could be ut, fa, or sol, while F could be ut or fa.)  Whether modal ambiguity of a melody is problematic is a matter of opinion.  It's also not possible to say whether such a melody is in a major or minor key in modern tonal practice.

Comment: Or before the 18th century in fact, if Wikipedia is to be believed about the timing of the invention of _si._

Comment: I also came up with Mixolydian. On further examination, the first part uses A as a reciting tone and the latter part uses B (and a bit of A). Chants with more than one reciting tone sometimes are just called "Tonus Perigrinus." (  Falcon Tone and his brother Franchet?) I don't know if the "Wandering Tone" is a cop-out or if one could analyzing parts of the chant as transposed.

Comment: @ttw my understanding is that "tonus peregrinus" refers to a specific psalm reciting tone where the tenor is on A for the first half of the verse and G for the second half (it makes an appearance in the _te decet_ of Mozart's Requiem among many other places).  The Pater noster is not like this at all (and the B is only prominent in the oremus, which isn't necessarily the same piece).  Most liturgical chant sung by clergy and congregation is like this, cadencing on or near the reciting tone rather than far below it.  The chants with wider ranges are those to be sung by the choir.

Comment: E in hard hexachord = la, no mutation needed

Comment: @musarithmia it's not the same hard hexachord as the other notes, though; it's in the wrong octave.  An ascending minor third is re-fa or mi-sol, not la-ut.